# I'm going to get an IEM system but I need a mixer

Tags: mixer, monitors

I am going to buy an IEM system so I can hear my vocals. (I am the lead singer in a band)
I don't really care about hearing the music, I'll be able to. If my vocals are the only thing that I can hear in the IEM, that is fine.

So, I would need an mixer with an "Aux Send" correct?
Also, should I go for an unpowered mixer or powered mixer?
(I have 2 passive speakers and 1 powered speaker… It really just comes down to money I guess)

Also, I do have a powered mixer but I don't believe it's able to work with IEMs (No aux sends)
Maybe it'll work. I have no idea. Here is a pic.

Here is the front 
[image: Mixer Front] 
And here is the back 
[image: Mixer Back]

There isn't any way for my powered mixer to work as a power amp to power an unpowered mixer?

Answer (score 1):

You have two or maybe three options.  The first is to use the tape output as a feed for your IEM.  If you do this, you will get the final mix in your ear rather than just your vocal.

The second option is to use the effects send.  If you use the effects, then this won't be an option, but if you aren't using the effects, you can use the effects send as a monitor mix and send just your vocal out that way.

The final option is to grab your vocals before you get to the mixer in the first place.  You could use a dedicated pre-amp for the XLR from your mic.  If you get a preamp that includes more than one output, you can feed your IEM off one output while ideally providing a pass through of the signal to the sound board.  (For example, something like [this](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/USBDualPrePS?device=c&network=g&matchtype=&gclid=CPT9ldW42LwCFYRQ7AoduSgAHg) would probably get the job done, though that was just the first thing I found.)